# Select file by index - Shortcuts to Interactive Staging

Tags: git

I am aware of Git's [Interactive Staging functionality](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging), but it is a bit clunky if only one or two files should be added to the staging area.

Is there a command to add a file by index to the staging area?

**Example:**

Let's take the example from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15914878/2021763) (to a similar question).

```
$ git status -s
M a/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt
M another/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt
```

Then comes the unknown command:

```
$ git add #2
```

Which would result in:

```
$ git status -s
M a/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt
A another/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have not found an "official" solution, I created my own [script](https://gist.github.com/gillesB/91c27f11a2a35f686682597b79cbec8f).

It is rough and barely tested:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

git_status=`git status --porcelain`

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
then
  # Get modified files and their index
  # nl: numbers the lines
  echo "$git_status" | nl 
  exit 0
fi

if ! [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
  echo "Sorry integers only"
  exit 1
fi

line=`echo "$git_status" | sed "${1}q;d"` 
# remove first 4 chars. E.g. M and some spaces
file=`echo "$line" | cut -c3-`
git add $file
git status -s
```

Usage:

I created an alias `gai` for the script:

```
$ gai
     1   M README.md
     2   M package.json

$ gai 2
 M README.md
M  package.json
```